# Error: (1062, “Duplicate entry 'search-laft_cadaveres_cni_identificados' for key 'django_content_type_app_label_model_76bd3d3b_uniq'”)

Tags: django, django-models

If someone can do me a favor to help with this error, I would appreciate it very much. Every time I run the command `python manage.py migrate` search to migrate my models, I get this error, although it performs well migrations to my database data:

```
Error: (1062, "Duplicate entry 'search-laft_cadaveres_cni_identificados' for key 'django_content_type_app_label_model_76bd3d3b_uniq'")
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Well it means that you added a second entry `laft_cadaveres_cni_identificados` for a certain column that was marked unique, hence the database rejeted it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help

Comment: What happens is that in my model I don't have any column that is marked as unique, so that's why I don't understand why I get the error

Comment: a `OneToOneField` is for example also unique. On MySQL you can run `DESC table_name` to check how the table has been constructed. For other databases, there is likely another query with similar results.